# PHP Include Path Problems

Tags: php, path, include

Setting the include path is really confusing me.  I must be missing something important.

So I have the following scripts in the public_html folder of my server.

```
    photoGallery.php
    header.php
```

I have my htaccess file set to redirect a url with the following structure to photoGallery.php

```
RewriteRule ^gallery/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)-([^/]+)$ photoGallery.php?imageName=$2 [L]
```

So something like this...

```
http://localhost/gallery/roofing/1-picture-of-roofing
```

Would resolve to...

```
http://localhost/photoGallery.php?imageName=1
```

The problem is there is a PHP include inside of photoGallery.php that will not resolve if the URL has been rewritten.

```
    include 'header.php'
```

So I would like to set the php include path so it will resolve no matter what.  Here's what I've tried...

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . "../../../");
include 'header.php';
```

I've also tried setting the path like so...

```
// get_include_path() returns .:/opt/lampp/lib/php
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . "/opt/lampp/public_html");
include 'header.php';
```

I've never been able to successfully set the include path.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: BTW, Mod_Rewrite doesn't affect includes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try :

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/header.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a call to: http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php to the same script as

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . "/opt/lampp/public_html");
```

And then adjust "/opt/lampp/public_html" according to the getcwd() output.